# Unable to attach to a weblogic server using jProfiler GUI

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, performance-testing, jprofiler

I've started the server (Weblogic 10.3.3) from Eclipse and I'm trying to attach to it through jProfiler GUI. weblogic.Server is displayed in the list of available JVMs but when I try to attach to it I get the following error:

It is not possible to attach to an elevated process, if the jProfiler GUI is not elevated itself. Please restart jProfiler GUI as an administrator. 

 
However, I don't have administrative privileges on the machine I work on, so I was wondering whether there's any workaround for this? Is there any way to solve this issue without having to start the application as an administrator? 

 
FYI: I have the jProfiler Eclipse plugin.

Comment: How can you start or restart the server if you don't have admin privileges?

Answer (score 0):

When Jprofile is started you can choose what server you are trying to profile.Jprofiler has weblogic as one of the listed server. Once you select the server in jprofiler, jprofile will ask for the location of startup script. Jprofiler will create a modified startup script and it can start the weblogic server and connect.

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. The problem was that the server started well but I didn't see the application being deployed.

Comment: @SagarAiya Then you likely selected the wrong start script in the integration wizard

Comment: @IngoKegel Oh, It appears that the application is being deployed however, it takes a really long time for the classes being monitored (those from the application) to appear on the jprofiler memory views. I was wondering whether the application url needs to be changed? Also, how do I know when the deployment is complete?